# How do I compare and meaningfully rank $z$-scores?

Tags: statistics

I have an array comprised of unique factors $\vec{x}$. For each factor I have two z-scores, one computed at time $t_0$ and the other at time $t_1$. We can denote these z-score arrays as $\vec{z}_{t_0}$ and $\vec{z}_{t_1}$ respectively.

My goal is to create a new ordered array $\vec{d}$ that ranks each factor $x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_n$ according to how much their z-score changed from time $t_0$ to time $t_1$.

My question is, is it more meaningful to compute the percent difference i.e. $\frac{\vec{z}_{t_1} - \vec{z}_{t_0}}{\vec{z}_{t_0}}$ and rank based on that or to compute the absolute difference $\vec{z}_{t_1} - \vec{z}_{t_0}$ and rank based on that. Or is there some hybrid approach that is preferable?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you know if you are chiefly interested in absolute or relative change?

Comment: If you're more interested in each persons relative improvement then, I might suspect that normalizing to the first score (taking percentages) might be better, but I don't know with any good deal of certainty

Comment: I believe I am more interested in relative change, but is it even that meaningful?